# Как сделать магазин в игре, чтобы можно было покупать игровые вещи за игровые деньги?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Не могу сделать что бы монеты сохранялись после раунда то есть суммировались и что бы в магазине они были суммарно.
Например за 2 раунда собрал по 5 монет в магазине суммарно что бы было 10 монет.Как это можно сделать помогите пожалуйста

Как сделать корректное сохранение, счет и суммирование монет в unity?

[image: может код как нибудь поможет вам]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сохранять результат в базу данных к конкретному пользователю

Comment: как это сделать ? могу как нибудь связаться с тобой что бы ты мне помог ?)

Comment: я этим заниматся не хочу это долгий процесс , надо устонивить базу данных на сервер , создать таблицы и логику , только после подключится к базе

Comment: а проще нельзя сделать ? что бы просто копились монеты?

Comment: игра оффлайн на телефончик

Comment: чтобы они копились сохраняйте их тогда в файл или в локальную базу SQLite